# Server.mappath confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is a little confusion in my mind about server.mappath
which is correct and what's the difference betwwen these two

```
FileUpload1.saveAs(Server.MapPath("~/User/images/")+"ankush.jpg"));

FileUpload1.saveAs(Server.MapPath("~/User/images")+"ankush.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct way of using MapPath() would be:

```
FileUpload1.saveAs(Server.MapPath("~/User/images/ankush.jpg"));
```

or if you insist:

```
FileUpload1.saveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/User/images"),"ankush.jpg")));
```

MapPath() doesn't append a trailing backslash to the mapped path because it has no way of knowing if the path is a directory or a file (it doesn't check if the given path actually exists)

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use this way

```
FileUpload1.saveAs(Server.MapPath("~/User/images/ankush.jpg"));
```

Reason : because if you already know the path then why break down the filename separately
If the filename was getting passed by parameter then you could do

```
FileUpload1.saveAs(Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/User/images/{0}", fileName)));
```